# how to translate `extend`

Tags: idiom

```
I have extended a casual friendly greeting towards her.
```

Specially how do you translate the word `extend` in this context?

Also How do you translate this:

```
I am stating it outright!
```

Comment: You have two different questions. Every thread should focus on **one question**. So, in future please ask a separate question for any issue. Then also make the title more specific to address your problem (e.g. How to translate [word in question] in [context]). This allows future visitors to find this question. Also, as @Vogel612 also indicated, you should give further information on what you've already tried in order to solve the problem on your own. Otherwise people might answer things you already know.

Comment: I'm not sure about how to phrase it yet, but I would translate "to extend a greeting" to "begrüssen" and "casual" to "flüchtig". Something along "Ich begrüsste sie mit einer flüchtigen Handbewegung", provided there was a hand wave. Or, if it was a nod of your head: "Ich begrüsste sie mit kurzem Kopfnicken."

Answer (score 6):

> I am stating it outright!

can be translated as

> Ich sage es klar heraus!

or

> Ich sage es [unverblümt](http://www.dict.cc/?s=unverbl%C3%BCmt)!

---

> I have extended a casual friendly greeting towards her.

could be translated as

> Ich hieß sie (herzlich) willkommen. [[Source]](http://www.dict.cc/?s=to+extend+a+welcome+to+sb.)

Comment: As already mentioned in another comment: Please try to use translation pages (or google) before posting here.

Comment: "a casual friendly greeting" equals "herzlich willkommen heißen"??? I don't think so.

Comment: `extend a greeting` seems to translate to `willkommen heißen` (http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2003-11-07/business/0311070324_1_rule-violation-orientation-new-owners) And concerning what Americans understand by `casual friendly` I would also go in German with the standard `herzlich`.

Comment: `I am stating it outright` has some more translations in different registers: `Ohne Scheiß`, `Ey, ich schwör`, `auf hochdeutsch`, `Ich will ehrlich sein.`, …

Comment: @Em1: Please don't take this the wrong way, your contributions to this page are appreciated, but please try for a little less emphatic responses and avoid knee-jerk reactions. "Casual" may indeen mean "flüchtig" like you understood it. It can, however, also mean "informal", so Baz' solution is not as far off the mark as it may appear to you. In fact, the English original implies a more friendly greeting than merely a curt gesture of acknowledgement like a "flüchtige Handbewegung" or a short nod. Nix für ungut!

Comment: @Mac Fair enough.

Comment: _Ich sage es, wie es ist!_